# Login only works for admin

Tags: django, authentication

I'm working on a project in Django and trying to use the built in view at

> django.contrib.auth.views.login

I have

> (r'^accounts/login/$', auth_views.login)

in urls.py

```
{% if form.errors %}
<p>Your username and password didn't match. Please try again.</p>
{% endif %}

<form method="post" action="{% url 'django.contrib.auth.views.login' %}">
{% csrf_token %}
<table>
<tr>
    <td>{{ form.username.label_tag }}</td>
    <td>{{ form.username }}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>{{ form.password.label_tag }}</td>
    <td>{{ form.password }}</td>
</tr>
</table>

<input type="submit" value="login" />
<input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" />
</form>
```

in the registration/login.html that django requires to use the login view.

I verified that the user/password combination is correct using the admin page.  In the accounts/login page, if I type in my admin username/password it will log me in, but it won't do it for regular users.  Why would that be?

Answer (score 0):

you dont use the login function directly as your view function.. and admin page is working because it isnot using your url-mapping.

you need

```
#views
from django.contrib.auth.views import login
def log_me_in(request):
   # todos.. authenticattion... 
   login(request, user)
```

and in urls

```
(r'^log_me_in/$', 'yourapp.views.log_me_in')
```

it is important **not** to name your login function the same as `login()` from auth.. otherwise you get stuck in `maximum recursion reached` or something like this.. meaning they end up calling each other and go into endless loop..

**[just read the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.login)**

Comment: Thanks for responding.  I think your way will also work, but are you sure you can't use django's view directly?  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/auth/default/#module-django.contrib.auth.views seems to suggest you can.